# Using git inside C++ rpogram (gitlib2 ? QT ?)

Tags: c++, git

I need to do basic 'git' manipulations inside a C++ program (git add, commit, status ...)

I heard about [gitqlib2](https://projects.kde.org/projects/playground/libs/libqgit2/) but I did not found any documentation or examples.

What is the best way of using git inside a c++ program ?

I'm ok to use QT and Boost libraries. If not, I can code a wrapper over 'popen', but it should be a pity.

**EDIT** : Since it is for a course project, the only external libraries that I'm allowed to use are the boost ones.

Comment: For most production scenarios I'd choose running git binary through system and popen as most reliable way.

Comment: That's what I ended to do, but it does not seem very clean. For example, in order to get the list of untracked files, I have to perform some ugly string manipulations on the output of "git status".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `gitqlib2` is a wrapper for https://libgit2.github.com/.  Depending on your needs, you can use `libgit2` directly since it's a C library.

I see that `gitqlib2` does have a `Doxygen.in` file, so running `Doxygen` on the source code may produce some documentation if you want to use the C++ wrapper.